# Magento 2 Error occured after upgrade : Warning: ltrim() expects parameter 1 to be string, array given

Tags: magento2, magento-2.1.9

Getting following error while compilation using this command : **php bin/magento setup:di:compile** after upgrade Magento **2.1.7** to **2.1.9** check below error for more information :

> Warning: ltrim() expects parameter 1 to be string, array given in
>   /MagentoRoot/setup/src/Magento/Setup/Module/Di/Compiler/Config/Chain/BackslashTrim.php
>   on line 61

Comment: Remove `var/*` folder and try

Comment: Already tried this but getting same error.

Comment: There is issue with 0 [indexed objects](https://github.com/magento/magento2/issues/8803)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Issue fixed after run following commands in root directory

644 permission for files

> find . -type f -exec chmod 644 {} \;

755 permission for directory

> find . -type d -exec chmod 755 {} \;

777 permission for var folder

> find ./var -type d -exec chmod 777 {} \;

And following commands for pub/media and pub/static

> find ./pub/media -type d -exec chmod 777 {} \;
>
> find ./pub/static -type d -exec chmod 777 {} \;

Answer (score 4):

I came across this and turned out to be an issue when you run integration tests at some point before running `bin/magento setup:di:compile`.

Integration tests generate some test modules in `app/code/Magento` which are then picked up by the `setup:di:compile` command.
[image]
I fixed this by removing the `Magento` folder from `app/code`.

Answer (score 1):

I would assume this is related to (read/write/execute) to var and pub directory.

> sudo chmod -R 777 var pub

Also, try clearing the cache

> sudo rm -rf var/cache/* var/generation/*

However it might be something to do with the di folder, this might also work:

1. Delete the di folder from the var directory
2. sudo php bin/magento setup:di:compile
3. Reset file permissions.

Comment: I have already tried this lots of times. but getting error every time.

Comment: delete vendor and reinstall. Have you tried this ?

Comment: FYI site is working fine but compilation not working. Also can you please tell me what needs to be reinstall ?

Answer (score 0):

I am facing the same issue after upgrading to Magento2.4.2-p1. I did some analysis on this and got the reason for this error.
Actually, Magento installed some new modules like Magento_TestModuleAsyncAmqp, Magento_TestModuleExtensionAttributes etc.
When you go to file

> app/code/Magento/TestModuleExtensionAttributes/Api/Data/FakeExtensibleTwoInterface.php

you will see

```
/**
     * test incorrect return type
     *
     * **@return int**
     */
    public function getExtensionAttributes();
```

So, here it is asking to provide class as return type instead of `@return int`
If you will add below class as return type then it should work.

> \Magento\TestModuleExtensionAttributes\Api\Data\FakeExtensibleTwoExtensionInterface|int

Try to provide class here and then run di:compile again after clearing cache, generation etc