# Magento 2.1.11 - Interceptor throwing ltrim expects 1 parameter to be string, object given warning exception

Tags: magento2, plugin, magento2.1.11, around-plugin

I want to make a plugin to do something around a custom made checkout method. I do have other interceptors working prior to adding this, but this one I am getting a ltrim warning.

> CRITICAL: Exception: Warning: ltrim() expects parameter 1 to be string, object given in /mnt/magento_prime/vendor/magento/framework/Code/Generator/EntityAbstract.php on line 152 in /mnt/magento_prime/vendor/magento/framework/App/ErrorHandler.php:61

I have no clue what should be causing this, and it is giving me a headache.

**Vendor\Module\etc\di.xml**

```
<!--Snippit-->

<type name="Vendor\Module\Model\Magento_Checkout\PaymentInformationManagement">
    <plugin name="Vendor_Module::Model_PaymentInformationManagement" type="Vendor\Module\Plugin\Vendor_Module\Model\PaymentInformationManagementPlugin" />
</type>

<!-- Snippit -->
```

**Vendor\Module\Plugin\Vendor_Module\Model\PaymentInformationPlugin**

```
namespace Vendor\Module\Plugin\Vendor_Module\Model;

class PaymentInformationManagementPlugin
{

    public function aroundSavePaymentInformationAndPlaceOrder(
        \Vendor\Module\Model\Magento_Checkout\PaymentInformationManagement $subject,
        \Closure $proceed,
        $cartId,
        \Magento\Quote\Api\Data\PaymentInterface $paymentMethod,
        \Magento\Quote\Api\Data\AddressInterface $billingAddress = null
    ){
        // run parent method and capture int $orderId
        $orderId = $proceed($cartId, $paymentMethod, $billingAddress);

        return $orderId;
    }
}
```

I have looked at questions like:

[Magento 2 Error occured after upgrade : Warning: ltrim() expects parameter 1 to be string, array given](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/195519/magento-2-error-occured-after-upgrade-warning-ltrim-expects-parameter-1-to)

But the solutions, like removing the var folders, do not work.