# Product is not updating in Magento 2

Tags: magento2, magento2.2, php-7

I am getting an error while updating a product

> Warning: trim() expects parameter 1 to be string, array given in
>   D:\xampp-7.1.23\htdocs\indiahicks\vendor\magento\module-eav\Model\Entity\AbstractEntity.php
>   on line 942

here is the video [link](https://www.useloom.com/share/6b395be00ed04ab4bc43f6284ac9e28e) as well

Comment: Which Magento Version you are using?

Comment: version is magento 2.2.6

Comment: if you are using cpanel then try to change php version to 7.2.x and let me if its works

Comment: magento 2.2.6 do not support php 7.2. I am using php 7.1.25

Comment: https://github.com/magento/magento2/issues/12300

Comment: try to apply last commit fix `* 109a27eb8bd2e5b8f37fcb84ef4c0d19490a5e16`

Comment: there is no app/code/Magento/Catalog/Model/Product/Attribute/Backend/Sku.php in my code, not even Magento folder in code folder

Comment: I was getting same issue before, check here for more information : https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/195519/magento-2-error-occured-after-upgrade-warning-ltrim-expects-parameter-1-to

Comment: it should be in your `vendor` folder you are using composer dude so your path should be `vendor/magento/module-catalog/Model/Product/Attribute/Backend/Sku.php`

Comment: @AasimGoriya I have already done with this solution, it didn't work for me

Comment: You can also check provided link by @AasimGoriya it may be permission issue to update your folder permission ones

Comment: both solutions didn't work

Comment: its very sad i will surely download magento 2.2.6 default and check this issue.

Comment: I have checked with default magento 2.2.6 and its working very well check external modules that may creating this issue.

Comment: It was working fine, I have added magenot 2 layered navigation pro of Mageplaza and OneSetpCheckout of Amesty, but then I disabled and deleted those modules still I am facing this issue.

Comment: Thanks a lot, guys for your quick response, The error was in the database, someone change category directly from the database.