# After upgrade to 2.4.2-p1 getting error on compile "Fatal error: Uncaught TypeError: rtrim() expects parameter 1 to be string"

Tags: magento2, magento2.4, php-7.4

Getting error after upgrade to 2.4.2-p1, on di:compile command

> Application code generator... 3/9 [=========>------------------]  33%
> 1 min 380.0 MiBPHP Fatal error:  Uncaught TypeError: rtrim() expects
> parameter 1 to be string, bool given in
> setup\src\Magento\Setup\Module\Di\Code\Scanner\PhpScanner.php:95

Comment: What operating system are you using?

Comment: do compile and check in magento root you can see errorlog.php or phperrorlog file. this will indicate exact error location.

Comment: I have resolved this and added an answer here
https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/195519/magento-2-error-occured-after-upgrade-warning-ltrim-expects-parameter-1-to

Answer (score 0):

try defining the PHP version in the command, i use

> php-7.2 bin/magento setup:di:compile

Yours may be

> php-7.4 bin/magento setup:di:compile

Comment: I already tried this but still getting the same error